# How to create a generic transformation pipeline in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, pipeline, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a basic transformation pipeline in swift.  Here is what I have so far

```
import Foundation

protocol Transformation {
    associatedtype Target
    func transform(_ input: Target) -> Target
}

struct LowercaseTransformation: Transformation {
    func transform(_ input: String) -> String {
        return input.lowercased()
    }
}

struct ReverseTransformation: Transformation {
    func transform(_ input: String) -> String {
        return String(input.reversed())
    }
}

struct Pipeline<T> where T: Transformation {
    let transformations: [T]

    func run(_ input: T.Target) -> T.Target {
      var output = input
      transformations.forEach { output = $0.transform(output) }
      return output
    }
}

let pipeline = Pipeline(transformations: [LowercaseTransformation(), ReverseTransformation()]) // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
let input: String = "Hello World"
let output = pipeline.run(input)
print(output)
```

My issue is related to the use of generics, but I have been unable to figure out how to get around it while keeping the Transformation protocol and the Pipeline struct reusable...

---

Just had another try.. this works with one Transformer in the array or even multiple of instances of the same Transformer but as soon as the Array contains different Transformers it breaks...

```
protocol Transform {
    associatedtype Target
    func transform(input: Target) -> Target
}

struct Transformer: Transform {
  func transform(input: String) -> String {
    input+"_Transformed"
  }
}

struct AnotherTransformer: Transform {
  func transform(input: String) -> String {
    input+"_Morphed"
  }
}

struct TransformPipeline<Target, Transformer: Transform> where Transformer.Target == Target {
  private let transforms: [Transformer]

  init(transforms: [Transformer]) {
        self.transforms = transforms
    }

    func run(input: Target) -> Target {
        var output = input
        for transform in transforms {
          output = transform.transform(input: output)
        }
        return output
    }
}

let transformations = [Transformer()]
let pipeline = TransformPipeline(transforms: transformations)

print(pipeline.run(input: "input"))
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simplified version is to use only the `Pipeline` struct and let it hold an array of functions

```
struct Pipeline<Target> {
    typealias Transformer = (Target) -> Target
    let transformations: [Transformer]

    func transform(_ input: Target) -> Target {
        var output = input
        for transformation in transformations {
            output = transformation(output)
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

and then use like

```
let pipeline = Pipeline<String>(transformations: [{ $0.uppercased() }, { String($0.reversed()) }])
```

To make use of Pipeline somewhat cleaner we could declare some static properties for our functions

```
extension Pipeline where Target == String {
    static let uppercased: Transformer = {
        { $0.uppercased() }
    }()

    static let reversed: Transformer = {
        { String($0.reversed()) }
    }()
}

let pipeline = Pipeline<String>(transformations: [ Pipeline.uppercased, Pipeline.reversed])
```

Comment: I like this implementation a lot, but this seems to be geared towards transformations being tiny.  In the actual scenario I'm implementing the transformations can be complex, the can take configuration as parameters and can rely on external configurations that the need to read, the might even have to call external API's,,,

Comment: I got the impression this was simple operations. If you are going to make asynchronous calls to external API's etc then maybe Combine is the best solution

Comment: Might be true, but I'm actually trying to avoid Combine.  I guess the real question is, how (if possible) do you create a collection of protocols that does not necessarily have the same underlying class but does have the same associatedtype...